# A list of properties of the free group of rank two

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Understanding the free group of rank two is (as far as I know) very important to many different problems. I thought it would be helpful (for me and for others) to know more about it. Can anyone give me a list of interesting/useful properties of elements of $F_2$?

Comment: 1. It's free 2. It has two generators. :P

Comment: 3. It has three properties.

Comment: SO is it the abelian or the non-abelian, or both that are 'very important' ?

Comment: I think this question has the potential to be interesting. The free group of rank two is somehow "different" from other free groups, and so if the question was edited to be about this difference then it would be fine. For example, the natural map $\operatorname{Out}(F_2)\rightarrow\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z\times Z})$ is an isomorphism, but the same is not true of free groups of higher rank. As another example, Cohen, Metzler and Zimmerman gave a really explicit description of bases for $F_2$, but similar descriptions don't hold/are not know to hold for free groups of higher rank.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, it has as subgroups the free groups of rank $1$ and $0$.

Nonobviously, it has as subgroups the free groups of all countable ranks.  This follows from the fact that it's "SQ universal".  That is, every countable group can be embedded in one of its quotients.

For a list of other interesting facts, there is always the Wikipedia article on free groups.

Comment: Thx for the pointer: SQ-universality can be thought of as a measure of largeness or complexity of a group.